# How to use not personal account web3

Tags: contract-development, web3js, accounts, private-key

In my previous post I got answer but still I need some clarifications 
let say when deploying contract with node js we have this line

```
 try {
    web3.personal.unlockAccount(web3.eth.coinbase, password);
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    return;
}
```

which is unlocking account to make transaction for contract creation .

What if account is created with this way

```
web3.eth.accounts.create([entropy]);
```

And I have private key encyrpted somewhere on the system how I shall use it to unlock (or jsut use account) account let say after a week from it's creation ?

Also can u give details on what does entropy do 
?

Is it like password in case of personal account ?

Thanks and sorry if questions are similar , there are not much resources to get more detailed info

Comment: You usually want to use a locally stored account, not create a server-side account that is not supported by most of Ethereum servers. Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67736753/using-local-private-key-with-web3-js

Answer (score 1):

Having a private key you can create a new account with [web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(account|privateKey)](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#wallet-add)

You can use your account normally after.

```
// Create account
var account = web3.eth.accounts.create([entropy]);

// Load account
web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(account)

// Set the account as the default
web3.eth.defaultAccount = account.address;

// Use it normally
web3.eth.signTransaction(transactionObject, address [, callback])
```

In the `transactionObject` you can omit the `from` parameter and the default account will be used.

#### Make sure to read the documentation

- [web3.eth.accounts.create](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#create)
- [account object](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#returns)
- [web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#wallet-add)
- [web3.eth.signTransaction](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction)
- [Entropy in computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(computing))

Comment: That is not he answer to my question . ? 
I know about personal and tx , please read question again .

Comment: Correct typos and rephrase to make it more clear. Ask less questions. I will read your question after

Comment: Sure I will rephrase the question

Comment: if you import a geth V3 wallet to web3, how do you make it the default address? I can't get web3 to successfully sign txns when using `web3.eth.accounts.wallet.decrypt`. I try to set web3.eth.accounts.wallet[0]['address'] to default after decrypting. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I think I should be using `web3.eth.accounts.decrypt` perhaps instead of the wallet methods, but there's no clear explanation on this.